# Database Support on the Server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database

Is it necessary to have database support on the server on which I want to upload my website which I want to create using wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress uses a MySQL database.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking us to replicate the [requirements documentation](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) for a particular piece of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, if you want to troubleshoot MySql (the database wordpress uses) issues. Most hosts have PhpMyAdmin, the Administrative tool online to administer your MySql database for free, so in essence you will be supporting your own hosted database using that tool provided by your website host.

Hope this helps and let me know if you need more info.

~Barb